# shorter preventDefault() with iron:router when using pathFor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I use the meteor package iron:router to route my templates. I tested my code in the browser and I see no reload when I click links. When I run my code on mobile the page is reloading. I know that I can disable this via a helper like:

```
Template.mytemplate.helpers({
      myhelper: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

to keep my code simple I don't would like to create helpers for every template where I use links with:

```
<a href="{{pathFor: 'myroute'}}">mylink</a>
```

Is there a easy way to handle this to minimalize redundant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write the same helper in every template. You can reuse one for all templates:

```
Template.registerHelper('preventDefault', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: this looks like a global helper that I was looking for. how I have to use this in the template?

Comment: You should be able to use it the same way you would have used the helper you made in your original post. It's an interesting problem you're having, though. I have not needed to use preventDefault on `<a>` tags that use pathFor for mobile. They behave the way iron:router intends them to behave. Another solution might be to register a global click event handler for anchor tags `Template.body.events({ 'click a':function(e) { e.preventDefault(); })`

Comment: ok this is very strange. I have not really much code yet and just created some routes and some pubs/subs. I also recognized that when I tap and hold for some milliseconds on a link (not to long that it opens a context menu on iphone) it works like it should work even without any of these workarounds. when I make a short tap its moving to the url and reloads the page and the server is publishing all the collections again (see this in server log). do you have a clue what might cause this behavior? it looks like the iphone can distinguish taps and longer taps. I use iPhone 6 Plus

Comment: ok I found the "bug" I´m was using a famous package (mjn:famous) and it looks like the package is causing the strange behavior per default.

Comment: Cool glad things worked out. Just remember you can register global helpers and events! Very useful.

Comment: jep ;) but now I fixed my problem with another problem I need the famono package^^

Comment: Huh.. never heard of Famous before until now. Looks like you can probably do whatever you want without it! Though I'm sure it makes certain things a lot easier

Comment: FYI: the `mjn:famous` package was my problem using `raix:famono` now and I don´t need to handle this anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup. I've been looking at famo.us and the animation engine seems pretty amazing.